# I want to get the name of the client whose id corresponds to the client_id present in the projects table (where client_id is the foreign key)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

As already described, I want to get the name of the client whose id corresponds to the client_id present in the projects table (where client_id is the foreign key).

##### Relationship defined in the `Client` model

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}
```

##### Relationship defined in the `Project` model

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

##### `ClientController`

```
public function index()
{
    $clients = Client::withCount('projects')->withCount('tasks')->get();  
    return view('client.index', compact('clients'));
}
```

##### `ProjectController`

```
public function index($id)
{   
    $projects = Project::where('client_id', $id) ->withCount('tasks')->get();
    return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

In the project view of that client I want to see the following line: `List of projects related to (client name)`

Anyone who can kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a client ID, so why do a search of projects based on a foreign key column? One of the advantages of a framework like Laravel is you don't need to think about column names like `client_id`, you just think about relationships. In this case you want the client information, so get that model and then use `load()` to get the relationship information.

Things get a bit complicated if you want the count of each project's tasks. You need to specify a closure as part of the call to `load()`.

```php
public function index($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id)
        ->load(['projects' => function ($q) {
            $q->withCount('tasks');
        }]);
    return view('project.index', compact('client'));
}
```

Now in your blade you can do this:

```html
<p>List of projects related to {{ $client->name }}</p>

@foreach ($client->projects as $project)
    <div>{{ $project->name }} has {{ $project->tasks_count }} tasks</div>
@endforeach
```

---

You should also look into [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) to avoid having to do the lookup of the client model manually. Once your route is properly specified, your controller method can look like this:

```php
public function index(Client $client)
{
    $client->load(['projects' => fn ($q) => $q->withCount('tasks')]);
    return view('project.index', compact('client'));
}
```

Comment: since I am new it seems a bit difficult what you wrote

Comment: If you find the closure intimidating you can just do `load('projects')` and then in the template just do `$project->tasks->count()`. It's simpler but it does cause more database queries.

Comment: but what does that $q refer to? i can't find this in the documentation

Comment: When you use a closure for filtering relationships the function is passed the result of the relationship method so that you can do what you want with it. You're working with the `projects` relationship so in this case `$q` is the instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` that's returned by the `Client::projects()` method.

Comment: can you tell me where i find this information please?

Comment: from what i'm understanding, in $q am i going to put the relationship?

Comment: $q is the relationship. You are changing it so you can get the task counts. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

ProjectController:

```php
public function index($id)
    {   
     
        $projects = Project::where('client_id', $id)        
               ->withCount('tasks')
               ->with('client')
               ->get();
        return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

The model should have a relationship `client` in it.
Note - you may want to remove the `compact` statement.

In the view you should be able to get the name using:

```php
@foreach($projects as $project)
    {{ $project->client->name) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: So how do I get the client name in the view?

Comment: I'm new to Laravel, why should we use foreach if we only have one?

Comment: So in your project index view you are sending a collection/array of projects. There are many projects which you must loop through as `$project` and then output each project with information. Is this not what you want? Usually the index method would have a list of projects.

Comment: yes but in doing so, I print the name as many times as there are projects. I only need to print it once. How can I remedy this problem?

Comment: I think the other answer provided fits better to your needs in that case. You should use route model binding.

Comment: Can you answer this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284600/i-want-to-get-the-related-client-name-through-a-hasmanythrough-relationship