# I want to get the related client name through a hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I need to print on the view the name of the client that refers to the tasks of its projects through the interim relationship called projects.

I used a hasManyThrough relationship because I needed to get more information. Now I need to get the client name as described above.

*Relationship defined in the Client model:*

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Task::class, Project::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Project model:*

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Task model:*

```
public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

I've tried this but can't get the client name

*TaskController:*

```
public function index($id = NULL)
    {
        $tasks = Task::all();
        $project = Project::find($id)->load(['tasks']);     
        return view('task.index', compact('tasks','project'));
    }
```

In the task view of that task I want to see the following line:

"List of tasks related projects to (client name)"

Anyone who can kindly help me?

---

**clients**
*id* - integer
*name* - string

**projects**
*id* - integer
*client_id* - integer
*name* - string

**tasks**
*id* - integer
*project_id* - integer
*title* - string

Comment: can you provide the tables structure?

Comment: I added the other relationships to understand better

Comment: didnt you already get a response for a question like this?

Comment: no because in another question I was asking something else different

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need first to add a relationship on Task model:

```
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Client::class, Project::class);
    }
```

this relationship will allow you to get the client to whom the project containing this task belongs to.
Then on your TaskController :

```
    public function index($id = NULL)
    {
        $tasks = Task::with(['project', 'client'])->get();
        $project = Project::find($id)->load(['tasks']);     
        return view('task.index', compact('tasks','project'));
    }
```

Now the $tasks will have within them the project info + client info

Comment: I get: **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'projects.task_id' in 'field list'**